# How to append string to file in windows store app?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have windows store app for shopping. I have created Logfile to manage errors. But sometimes I get following error while appending data in file.

Here is my code:

```
        public static async void logError(string pagename, string functionname, string errordescription)
        {
            try
            {
                var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("errorLog.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, string.Format("{0}Date: {1} \t PageName: {2} \t FunctionName: {3} \t ErrorDescription: {4}", Environment.NewLine, DateTime.Now, pagename, functionname, errordescription));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

It write few lines but after some times, it throw following errors: 
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

I am not getting why this error throws. Can anybody please suggest me how to solve this?

Comment: `async void` should *only* be used for event handlers or similar functions, otherwise you have no way of detecting that the method finished. It's possible you tried to write to the file while a previous call was executing. Change the signature to `async Task` and await the log method, eg `await LogError...`. In any case, please post the full exception including the call stack. You can get this by calling `Exception.ToString()`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, sometimes it happen that it call to write even last call was executing. Can you please suggest me link or idea about how to work with "async Task"?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if we use "await" LogError while calling, we need to add "async" in signature of all the method which contain this call. And LogError call is in try-catch of almost methods. Is it good to add "async" in all method?

Comment: `async` doesn't do anything. It's just a marker for the compiler. It's `await` that actually does something - store away the execution context of the current thread, release the thread, await for the asynchronous operation to complete and then restore the context to the original thread.

Comment: If you don't want to await for the log operation to finish, you could use an ActionBlock to perform all writes sequentially in a background thread, or post it to a ConcurrentQueue and have a separate thread poll it and write any log messages. Perhaps though, you should find a logging library that already does this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos We can't user await in Catch and Finally. My most call of LogError are in catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this error is that you open/create a file on each LogError call. As these calls can happen asynchronously and in parallel there's a race condition in opening the log file. The second call will fail with the access deny error if the file is already open in the first call.

Even if you fix issues mentioned in comments about "sync" usages (that I recommend to do) it does not help to solve this problem.

There're several possible solutions:

1) create the Logger class that opens the file only once and then it serves LogError calls (mind concurrent call of LogError as well - lock on an object or use Mutex).

2) Lock entire LogError on an object or use Mutex. So, all your calls to LogError will be sequential and there will be no race conditions in accessing the log file.

3) Use unique file name on each LogError call (e.g. add a new GUID to a name).